# when click back button in activitygroup,it doesnt work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, activitygroup

In my app,i use a TabActivity with five tabs,each tab contain a ActvityGroup,each ActivityGroup manage more than one Activity.one of ActivtyGroups have two Activies:A and B, when click a button in A,it jump to B.when return to A,i want to display some changed data in B.what i meet is:

first, if i start B and some widget in B get focus,when click back button,app exit directly.i debug it and find when finish B it finish the app at the same time.second,if i start B and none of any widget get focus,when click back button,onKeyDown() in B does not work.

Here is my activitygroup,i ues viewanimator as container:

```
public class Group extends ActivityGroup 
{

    private Stack<String>aString;               
private LocalActivityManager manager;
private ViewAnimator animator;
private int ID;                              

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.group_products);

    aString = new Stack<String>();
    animator = (ViewAnimator) findViewById(R.id.pro_va_animator);
    manager = getLocalActivityManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Products_Category.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) 
{
    String id = "id" + ID++;
    aString.push(id);

    View view = manager.startActivity(id, intent).getDecorView();
    animator.addView(view);
    animator.setDisplayedChild(aString.size() - 1);
}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent,int requestCode)
{
    String id = "id" + ID++;
    aString.push(id);
    View view = manager.startActivity(id, intent).getDecorView();
    animator.addView(view);
    animator.setDisplayedChild(aString.size() - 1);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        int size = aString.size();
        if (size > 0) 
        {
            String topId = aString.pop();
            View view = manager.destroyActivity(topId, true).getDecorView();
            animator.removeView(view);
            if (size > 1) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    A subActivity=(A)(manager.getCurrentActivity());
    A.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    break;

}
}
```

In class B,i rewrite onKeyDown() to add some changed data in bundle:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode,KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        Log.e("prodcuts_3","inner");
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name",name);
        bundle.putString("price",price);
        bundle.putString("quantity",quantity);

        this.setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,this.getIntent().putExtras(bundle));
        this.finish();
        return this.getParent().onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

in class A:

```
public void handleActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        String price=data.getExtras().getString("price");
               ......
    }
}
```

thank you guys in advances!!

Comment: Does the onKeyDown() gets calls in the ActivityGroup when you press back from Activity B?

Comment: if I set one of EditText .requestFocus() in class B,eventhough it doesnt get focus(i mean it doesnt change color).it can return successfully,but it doesnt run onKeyDown() both in B and Group. but if one of EditText change color in class B,it run onKeyDown() in class B,and when program goes to the "finish()" line.it exit.

Comment: Please check these examples http://richipal.com/post/2624844577 and also http://androidgenuine.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following to your class which is called from class which extends TabGroupActivity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       return;
    }
```